# Use PHP:JWT INSIDE A function

Tags: php, jwt

I am using Composer PHP JWT plugin, and what I realised is that I can call this:

```
$jwt = JWT::encode($userData, $JWT_KEY);
```

in my PHP code, but I can not do this inside a function, is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: May be it has some namespace. you need to use it OR try to call it as \JWT instead of JWT

Comment: it has namespace, but what can i do with it? it's outside of function

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your namespace in each file, regardless of that file being included in the "main" script where you may have already declared the same namespace.

```
<?php
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
/*Zoom Video Communications, Inc. 2015*/
/*Zoom Support*/
class ZoomAPI{
```